# How do I continue using an iterator after calling take?

Tags: rust, iterator

I want to collect a few items from an iterator, then iterate through the rest, something like this:

```
let iterator = text.split_whitespace();
let first_ten_words = iterator.take(10).collect();

for word in iterator {
    // This should iterate over the remaining words.
}
```

This doesn't work because `take()` consumes the iterator.

Obviously I can use `split_whitespace()` twice and `skip(10)` but I assume that will do the splitting of the first 10 words twice, and therefore be inefficient.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: It may be a duplicate, but at least, this question and the accepted answer address the language general problem clearly.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`.by_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref) like this:

```
let iterator = text.split_whitespace();
let first_ten_words = iterator.by_ref().take(10).collect();

for word in iterator {
    // This should iterate over the remaining words.
}
```